# Telerik Wpf Controls Localization

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, localization, telerik

I have a `GridViewResource` that localize the telerik wpf gridview and set in the app.xaml.cs with the below code

```
public App()
{
    LocalizationManager.Manager = new LocalizationManager() { 
    ResourceManager = SR.GridViewResource.ResourceManager };
}
```

Also, I have `DataPagerResource` that localize `wpf datapager` but I don't know how to set this two resource in the `app.xaml.cs` (Both `GridViewResource` and `DataPagerResource`)

Comment: What does the documentation say? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: documentation say the same code that i used. that works correctly but i don't know how to set my DataPagerResource alongside the GridViewResource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should create and assign a custom localization manager, if I understand what you really want to do.

please refer to the official Telerik Documentation:

[Localization of RadControls for WPF](http://www.telerik.com/help/wpf/common-localization.html)